# Delete duplicate store in mail chimp

Tags: shopify, store, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I contacted mailchimp support because I have an issue with 'best sellers' pulling through sold out items - they told me its due to a duplicate store but theyre unable to delete it and have offered the advice below.

> Issue of duplicate stores in your account. The work around for the
>   issue would be to use the API playground or a REST client to delete
>   the duplicate store in the account. Before doing this, we want to
>   stress that this deletion can not be undone and could potentially
>   affect the sending of ecommerce automations/emails that you have in
>   the account. That being said, I am aware that your account was running
>   into issues with accessing the playground earlier. If you would like
>   to delete the duplicate store from the account, we'd recommend using
>   the DELETE call for the duplicate store through a REST client and
>   would recommend doing this with the assistance of a developer if
>   needed. The endpoint that you'll want to use to delete that store from
>   the account is as follows:
>   http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/#delete-delete_ecommerce_stores_store_id
>
> If you would like to use the work around of deleting the store from
>   the account using the API, we'd recommend recreating the ecommerce
>   automations in your account to make sure that they are using the most
>   current and only instance of the store connected to MailChimp. While
>   the issue of having duplicate stores is unfortunate enough, I do see
>   how not being able to access the playground and having to use a REST
>   client/outside application only complicates the resolution to this
>   issue.

From the answers they provided me with I can't figure out how to do it, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete that extra store using [Postman api client](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA7ZK_mNbVAhUMq48KHeC-DX4QFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHijzEyYDCcZZ2IwmkXnAMNH38KzA)

Example displayed in mail chimp doc

```
curl --request DELETE \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/MC002' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--include
```

You can use this [medium](https://medium.com/@dddotcom/intro-to-mailchimp-api-3-0-adding-members-to-a-mailing-list-and-testing-with-postman-f056d900e0d9) tutorial if you are new to postman and mail chimp api.

Answer (score 0):

get the list of your stores then confirm which store to delete then delete it.

Comment: these can be done use mailchimp api, if need help please contact me.